# Using Connectycube in Android (Kotlin), how can I send meta data to other users in a group chat

Tags: metadata, videochat, connectycube

I am using Connectycube's APIs and I would like to pass some data from one user to another user while video chatting. This data needs to be sent without being seen by either user. The results will be such that some graphics will appear on the recipients screen. This data does not have to be queued or stored anywhere. It is only valid while both user's are video chatting.

I need some direction on how to do this. I am developing this for Android and then later for iOS.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connectycube API has [System messages feature](https://developers.connectycube.com/android/messaging?id=system-messages). It should match your requests. Just get SystemMessagesManager from ConnectycubeChatService, create message, and send this message via manager. These messages aren't saved anywhere and thay will receive only to user which you put via

```
systemMessage.setRecipientId(58672);
```

On receiver side just set listener to listening these messages.